# Error: libnode.so.64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, node-modules, lib

I created a docker container on ubuntu with following packages: default-jdk, node.js, curl, git, 
  npm, python, make, gcc.

I'm trying to run this tool https://github.com/oasis-tcs/odata-openapi/tree/master/tools inside the container. All required dependencies (like node-gyp) have been installed and the tool itself can be installed using npm without any errors, just as described in the readme.

However, when trying to execute a command I always get this error:

```
Error: libnode.so.64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:18)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/odata-openapi/tools/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:21:16)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
```

So far I tried reinstalling node.js, node-gyp, installing packages like node-libs and different ubuntu versions. The tool works fine on the host system.

Does anyone know how to handle this? It might be really simple, but so far I don't know how to proceed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If you did, how did you solve it? I'm facing the same.

Comment: Yes it was solved. From what I recall, it worked using Node.js version 8.10. I suspect version 10 would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a mismatch installation with nodejs.

It is important you make `npm i` after having installed the right version of nodejs.

On a host, this arises when nodejs has been upgraded after `npm i`. In this case do:

`npm clean-install`

And voila.

For your specific docker use case: You should make sure you installed nodejs AND did `npm i` from within the container, typically with `RUN` commands in your `Dockerfile`. This way you never have mismatches.

BUT, this arises if you install nodejs on the host and shared the volume to your container: avoid this and turn to what I was mentioning previously.